# Issue with Retrieving Filter Values in DataTables fnServerParams Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am facing an unusual issue with DataTables in my web application. I'm trying to retrieve the values of filters (specifically a date filter) in the fnServerParams callback of DataTables, but I'm not getting the expected results.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
var localCurrentFilters = {};

console.log(aoData);
aoData.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log("Key:", item.name, "Value:", item.value); // Debug log
    localCurrentFilters[item.name] = item.value;
});
// Call highlightActiveFilters with the current filters
highlightActiveFilters(localCurrentFilters);
```

In this code, I'm iterating through aoData to construct a localCurrentFilters object that is supposed to contain the values of the active filters.

However, while I can see the correct values (e.g.,"sSearch_1" = "01-11-2023~30-11-2023") when I log aoData directly,
[image]

the values associated with keys in localCurrentFilters often turn out to be empty.

[image]

This issue is particularly happening with date filters, where I expect to see a string formatted as "01-11-2023~30-11-2023", but end up with an empty or incomplete string.

I am looking for suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how I can effectively capture these filter values. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!